# radgridview.TableElement.Update Doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to update my gridview using an event on a contextMenu.
but it's not working..

here's my code:

**RowFormatting**

```
    void dgItemList_RowFormatting(object sender, RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemModel rowModel = e.RowElement.RowInfo.DataBoundItem as ItemModel;
        if (rowModel.Status == 2)
        {
           e.RowElement.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

**ClickEvent**

```
void Deactivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRowInfo row = dgItemList.CurrentRow;
        ItemModel rowModel =  row.DataBoundItem as ItemModel;

        if(UiHelpers.ShowConfirmForm("Do you want to Deactivate this Item?"))
        {
            ServiceResult result = _svc.UpdateItemStatus(rowModel.ItemID);
            if(result.Successful)
            {
                UiHelpers.ShowSuccessForm(rowModel.Description + " was successfully deactivated!");
                dgItemList.TableElement.Update(GridUINotifyAction.StateChanged);
            }

        }
    }
```

I am usng the `.TableElement.Update()` to run the `rowFormatting`.. however it isn't working... the function `UpdateItemStatus` just change the status of an item to `2`. I am really new to this so bear with me.

I'm using C#, and Telerik.

Comment: I already got it... I forgot to assign the status to the model.... there should be a `rowModel.Status = 2` before `dgItemList.TableElement.Update(GridUINotifyAction.StateChanged);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides making sure the **Status** is set, I would also recommend using the

```
row.InvalidateRow()
```

method, which will invalidate only one row, while the TableElement.Update is heavier update.

Besides, in the RowFormatting handler, you will also have to reset the introduced appearance modifications as the grid uses virtualization and elements are being reused during operations like scrolling, filtering, etc:

```
    void radGridView1_RowFormatting(object sender, RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowElement.RowInfo.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains("3"))
        {
            e.RowElement.DrawFill = true;
            e.RowElement.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            e.RowElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
        }
        else
        {
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.DrawFillProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.BackColorProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.GradientStyleProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        }
```

More information on row formattig can be found here: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-formatting-rows.html). And here you can read about the UI Virtualization: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-fundamentals-ui-virtualization.html)

Comment: If this works for you, please mark my post as answer.